# Python PyQt5 - Add rows to table

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a table created with 2 columns and 0 rows called tableWidget_Events.

Here's what the table and grid of buttons look like:
[image: table snip]

Using the value from the spinbox, I want to insert the button text as a row, so if the spinbox = 1 and I click walk, there should be a row created with 1 in the first column and walk in the second column.

Here's the code I have to connect the buttons:

```
    self.pushButton_SO.clicked.connect(self.add_table)
    self.pushButton_Walk.clicked.connect(self.add_table)
    self.pushButton_GB.clicked.connect(self.add_table)
    self.pushButton_FB.clicked.connect(self.add_table)
    self.pushButton_PU.clicked.connect(self.add_table)
```

Then the function to add the row:

```
def add_table(self):
    button = self.sender() # get button text
    row = self.spinBox_AB_TBL.value() #get value from spinbox

    rowPosition = self.tableWidget_Events.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget_Events.insertRow(rowPosition) #insert new row
    
    self.tableWidget_Events.setItem(row, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(self.spinBox_AB_TBL.value()))
    self.tableWidget_Events.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(button.text()))
```

The buttons are connected. I can print the button text to the console, and each button click adds a new row. Inserting the text is what I'm hung up on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTableWidgetItem` can not receive an integer as data, you must convert it to string, in your case the `value()` method of `QSpinBox` returns an integer, and this causes the problem.

Also if you want to insert you must indicate the appropriate position, in your case it should be `rowPosition-1` instead of `row`

```
def add_table(self):
    button = self.sender() # get button text
    row = self.spinBox_AB_TBL.value() #get value from spinbox

    rowPosition = self.tableWidget_Events.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget_Events.insertRow(rowPosition) #insert new row

    self.tableWidget_Events.setItem(rowPosition-1, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(row)))
    self.tableWidget_Events.setItem(rowPosition-1, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(button.text()))
```